# boot device missing or boot device failed (lenovo)

Tags: windows-10, bios, lenovo-laptop

how do i fix "boot device missing or boot device failed" like 2hours ago I updated bios using lenovo vantage, it all looked normal but few minutes after browsing web this error popped up. my device is lenovo yoga slim 7 ryzen 4700u amd radeon graphics 1tb ssd. please help, i have no experience with bios?

Comment: UEFI update often resets some settings. It does usually remember boot order & devices. But it may have turned UEFI Secure Boot back on, if you had it off? What operating system?

Comment: Get the Lenovo Diagnostic App and test your disk drive to see if that is the issue.